# Mysql Select WordPress Query – Display All posts information with category, tags and store them in another custom DB

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a query related to WordPress, which works perfectly in HeidiSql as a query,
but I want to save category & tags in another custom database with PHP (also, I could save other fields into custom DB except category & tags).

Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT   
wp_posts.ID as ID, wp_posts.post_author as post_author, wp_posts.post_date as post_date, wp_posts.post_content as post_content, wp_posts.post_title as post_title, wp_posts.post_status as post_status, wp_posts.comment_status as comment_status, wp_posts.post_name as post_name, wp_posts.guid as guid, wp_posts.post_type as post_type, wp_posts.comment_count as comment_count,    
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(wp_terms.name) from wp_term_relationships
        LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON(wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
        LEFT JOIN wp_terms ON (wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = wp_terms.term_id)
    WHERE wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id AND wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category') as post_category,
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(wp_terms.name) from wp_term_relationships
        LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON (wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
        LEFT JOIN wp_terms ON(wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = wp_terms.term_id)
    WHERE wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id AND wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'tags') as post_tags
FROM wp_posts
WHERE wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array( 'action', 'comedy' ),
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'tags',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array( 'action', 'comedy' ),
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    $query->the_post();
    echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks Jivani but,it's handwrite php code and just using wordpress DataBase :)